# Is a difference of logs a number on the log scale or original scale?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Suppose on day 2 you have \$$101$ while on day1 you had \$$100$:

- $\frac{101}{100} - 1 = 0.01$ growth rate (linear)
- $\log(\frac{101}{100} - 1) = -4.60517$ OR
- $\log(101) - \log(100) = 0.009950331$

If I was to use the phrase 'log growth rate' to describe the change in wealth, which is the correct one, if any?

I notice that the 3rd one, $0.009950331$ is very close to $0.01$, the first one. Is that coincidence?

Comment: Depends what you mean by log growth rate? e.g. do you mean it as in this link? https://academics.hamilton.edu/economics/cgeorges/macro-topics-files/growth.pdf

Comment: As for your second question, it is not a coincidence: $\log(1+r)\approx r$ for $r$ small. Yours is the case $r=1/100$

Comment: I was asking on the assumption that there's a canonical, objective definition. I never realized the definition was up in the air!

Comment: On the linked pdf, it looks like  they divide cumulative log growth by number of time units (years in their example) :/

Comment: BUt that seems like an avg. annual growth rate. IN my case I'd like day to day growth rate on a log scale.

Comment: The linked pdf has a multiperiod example. Terminology aside, the first and third calculations are most reasonable when discussing any notion of "growth rate" between two periods, and I would probably call the third calculation a "log approximation" to the first one.

Comment: Your second calculation wouldn't even make sense in general; e.g. what if you had $99 on day 2?...you can see the problem

Comment: Thanks for the info @Golden_Ratio. The result from the 3rd formula then is not on the log scale but in fact on the original linear scale then?

Comment: sure you should interpret the third calculation as you would a regular growth rate, just an approximation.  Note both the first and third calculation are unitless (they both involve ratios)